# Will modules proposal for C++14/17 make it possible(easy) for other native languages to be used to generate modules?

Tags: c++

this might sound weird, 
but I was thinking about modules proposal and wondered if it is possible for example that in future Haskell code could be exposed (as a module) in a way that C++ can use it(lets say list of T in 
Haskell  maps to `vector<T>`).
So do modules make that easy, possible, or it is no change compared to current status (C++11)?

Comment: Haskell can already be exposed to C++ http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Calling_Haskell_from_C

Comment: it looks kind of ugly since it is C. :) Im talking about sending const& vec<int>... and getting (const ofc) vector<int> as result

Comment: Not gonna happen: `std::vector` is a poor choice for use in a portable ABI. For starters, its layout depends on what standard library is being used. Being a template could also make it depend on the compiler flags that were used. There is a reason everyone falls back to C for this.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes can you elaborate... I thought that ignoring the stack part every vector is the same(continuous storage). And stack part isnt really important , it is not data, just pointers, afaik

Comment: But the stack part *is* really important: it is the part that knows the size and capacity. Without that the rest is not usable because you cannot even iterate properly over the contents.

Comment: what i meant is that if you have heap part you can easily fill in the stack parts... aka you have original stack, original heap data, you transfer heap data, and you can easily recreate stack part.

Comment: yes, you can do that but *not portably*, because some implementations will use a set of pointers, others will use a pointer and two integers, etc. And now consider all the variations in the order of those pointers/integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *possible* but I doubt it will make things easier.  My understanding is that the binary format of the information exported from modules would be compiler-specific, so it wouldn't provide a common ABI shared by all compilers on a platform.  The reason C is used as the glue between languages is that the C ABI on most platforms is pretty simple and is fixed, so it's not a moving target.  C++ implementations need a much richer ABI (name mangling format, exception hierarchy, object layout, vtable layout, RTTI representation etc.) and modules won't change that.